# Linq statement to return count and fields

Tags: c#, select, linq-to-sql, count

I need to be able to return the rows from a table where there are duplicates of a certain data column.

The table contains numerous columns, but I only need to return the lastname, firstname, email and the count of the emails (i.e. if there is more than one record with the same email address.)

I have tried the following which returns the correct records:

```
var _i = (from a in _db.WebPersonalInfos group a by a.Email into g where g.Count() > 1 orderby g.Key select g).ToList();
```

**However**, I need to revise this to only return lastname, firstname, email and the count(email).

I.E. "Smith", "Joe", "jsmith@gmail.com", 4

I am not sure how to accomplish this exactly.

Comment: What if records with the same email address have different first/last names?

Comment: There are times when the first and last names are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that records with the same email address have the same first/last names you could do:

```
var _i = (from a in _db.WebPersonalInfos 
          group a by a.Email into g 
          where g.Count() > 1 
          orderby g.Key 
          select new {
             LastName = g.First().LastName, 
             FirstName = g.First().FirstName, 
             Email = g.Key, 
             Count = g.Count()
          })
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes they do have the same first and last names. Thank you I will try what you suggested and return with the outcome

Comment: Ok two things. there are times when the same email address is used for different first and last names. and second when I used the SQL statement "SELECT lastname, firstname, email, COUNT(email) FROM dbo.WebPersonalInfo GROUP BY lastname, firstname, email HAVING (COUNT(email) > 1) ORDER BY email" it is returning about 100 less than the LINQ statement

Comment: `COUNT(email)` will only count _distinct_ email values - you should be using `COUNT(*)` instead to be equivalent

Comment: Thank you D Stanley for the direction. I ended up using "var _i = (from a in _db.WebPersonalInfos group a by new { a.Email, a.LastName, a.FirstName } into g where g.Count() > 1 orderby g.First().Email select new { LastName = g.First().LastName, FirstName = g.First().FirstName, Email = g.First().Email, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();" which gave the same count as the SQL.

Comment: Where is the closing } for select new { and how does one display the resulting list in a view?